# Can two Metro Apps shared data in WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Is there any common storage location in WinRT that can be accessed by multiple the Applications installed.
?
Scenarios is as below:
1. I will have two Metro Apps say App1 and App2
2. When App1 is started, I write some text data to storage
3. Later after some, time may be a day, App2 starts
4. When App2 starts, I need to read the data as stored in step 2 abov

Basically I want to share data in two applications in WinRT

Regards,
SRS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about [application data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx), then no - due to the sandboxed model of Windows 8 application execution. You can certainly write data and read data to/from the file system, but that requires the user granting explicit consent using the [file picker contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465174.aspx).

Your applications could alternatively store data externally, in the cloud or on-premises, and make service calls to read/write the data.  The [sharing contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh758314.aspx) and [protocol activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452686.aspx) is another option for collaborative applications.  Lastly, [Raw push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh761488.aspx) might work here here.

Comment: Your push notifications link is filled with `This material is not yet available. This placeholder topic is provided as an example of documentation that may be included in a later release.`

Comment: ugh, yeah, sorry about that... the public links aren't available quite yet, supposed to be when Win8 is launched in two days